# Are there protected class methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

A protected method basically means 'allow access for other objects of the same class'. By that definition, it doesn't make sense for protected class methods to exist. Is there such a thing as a protected class method in Ruby?

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense for protected methods to exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it kinda makes sense:

```
class Testo
  class << self
    protected

    def hello
      "world"
    end
  end
end

Testo.hello # => NoMethodError: protected method `hello' called for Testo:Class

class Pesto < Testo
  class << self
    def trello
      hello
    end
  end
end

Pesto.trello # => "world"
```

Comment: you might need to point to the OP that it might be a waste of time doing it as nothing is really private or protected in the real sense in Ruby

Comment: @bjhaid: `private` in Ruby is far from a waste of time even if it is easy to get around. There is a lot of value in a class having a well defined publicly accessible interface.